# mysql mass change ID to avoid duplication

Tags: mysql

I have two sets of data that need to be merged together. That's the easy part. The problem is that these sets of data have IDs that are the same. I'd like to iterate through one of the tables and simply increase all of the IDs by 10,000 so that when I merge the two tables, there are no identical ID's.

Is there any way to iterate through each row and increase the ID by 10,000 or any number?

Comment: Are the IDs autonumber, it should handle that for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, otherwise it would be pretty simple. Both datasets have IDs the correlate to other tables - so it's actually two tables that need to have unique ideas and the relationships must not be disrupted.

Comment: Be careful with your language. "Join" has a special meaning when talking about relational databases. It doesn't mean merging two tables into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET ID = ID + 10000
```

You could also do it in the process of merging the tables:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, other columns...)
SELECT ID+10000, other columns...
FROM Table2
```

Comment: Oh jeez, I had no idea it was that simple. And thanks for the merge query!

Comment: "relationships must not be disrupted" Make sure you have cascading updates. Or you'll need to hunt down every foreign key and update that too.

Comment: @LeeLouviere He's obviously going to have to do more than that when the data is moved into a new table -- all the joins will have to be redirected.

Answer (score 0):

While some database experts regard changing IDs as an absolute taboo it's actually not that hard - but there are a few caveats.

First, if you have foreign keys relating to your IDs, set them to auto-update:

```
ALTER TABLE `referring_table` DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk1`;
ALTER TABLE `referring_table` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`main_id`) REFERENCES `main` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Any changes in `main.id` will be passed on to `referring_table.main_id`.

Then, change the ID values:

```
UPDATE `main` SET `id` = `id` + 1000;
```

Finally, changing IDs might confuse `AUTO_INCREMENT` (at least in InnoDB, not sure for MyISAM). You might need to reset `AUTO_INCREMENT` to avoid nasty ID conflicts when inserting new data:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `main` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1;
ALTER TABLE `main` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1100; -- the value returned from last select + 1
```